# Внешнее подключение к rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq

Локально у меня стоит Rabbit mq. Мне необходимо, чтобы им могли пользоваться все извне. Как это сделать?

Comment: Ваш вопрос надо разделить на два. Первый - "какой порт использует rabbit mq?", второй - "как открыть порт?". Ответы на оба вопроса вы можете найти самостоятельно.

Comment: Тут описано как открыть внешний порт:
Секция - Открытие портов в брандмауэре
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms345343.aspx
Указавать необходимо нужный порт и описание правила тоже не помешает. Удачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Порт должен быть на сервере открыт (по умолчанию 5672 для rabbitMQ). Должен не блокироваться фаерволом или антивирусом.
2. Ваш сервер должен быть доступен из-вне по ip. В данном случае ваш локальный компьютер.
3. Клиенты в параметрах подключения к rabbitMQ должны указывать ip вашего сервера в качестве host.

Всё.

Никаких особых настроек в самом rabbitMQ насколько знаю производить не нужно.

Comment: я приблизился к решению : дело в том, что порт 5672 открыт только локально, внешне - нет! Кроме того, файл конфигураций rabbitmq отсутствует на windows. Теперь не понимаю, как этот порт выставить наружу(

Comment: Думаю, что конфиг rabbitmq не понадобится! (где он в win не знаю) Нужно подключиться к ip по нужному порту и всё) Читайте, как открывать порт. Хост резолвится по ip?

Comment: да, хост резолвится

Comment: AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ вот тут лежат настройки rabbitmq